# Mysterious Issues uploading images Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I hope someone can help me out here, something strange and mysterious is happening with my code.

I have a project which was working normally, but suddenly the images stopped to get uplodad.
I was working on an update method in the viewset when I realized that.

even more awkward is that I have two apps on my application one uploads the images normally and other doesn't.

I have tried to change the upload_to direction on the field which is not been uploaded and noticed that the new direction hasn't been applied, the destination folder is saved in the database with a previous direction (even though the picture never gets uploaded)

below you have the codes:

first the result of an update: notice the address

```
{
    "profile": 4,
    "card": "teste2",
    "points": 0,
    "created": "2022-11-29T16:05:33.502027Z",
    "updated": "2022-11-30T10:26:15.063888Z",
    "code": "673476",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:7000/medias/media/app_user/img_DENklQy.jpg"
}
```

now the models, notice the upload_to:

```
class MyCards(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(AppUserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    card = models.ForeignKey(Cards, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='mycards', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
```

my settings:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_URL = '/medias/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'medias' )
```

viewset, I have removed the update overriding method, to check if was a mistake on this method but it still doesn't work:

```
class MyCardsViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyCardsSerializer
    queryset = MyCards.objects.all()
```

Hope someone can help me with that, It's too awkward for me :/

Comment: Is ** [...] ** around image field present in your code? Or have you added it just in question?

Comment: I have added it with intention to make the line bold, I have removed it now to avoid any confusion

Comment: Something got messed up, I suggest you revert the changes back to when it was working and check the diff of what has been going on since then. It may turn out that the problem is not in the code, but in the environment or host settings. Check that path exists and set the right folder permissions (maybe your /medias/ is a symlink or NFS mount?).